# How di I get my headset to hear the audio

Tags: sound, headset

After a series of installing DroidCam and Zoom, the sound in my headset is no longer working. My headset is plugged to the sound port (green) at the rear

The audio in YouTube cannot be heard. I'm new in Ubuntu and any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that Settings was was missing. I restored using the sudo command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

The Settings is resored, I accessed the Sound tab and restored the Output to headset. I am now able to hear the audio on my speaker